# Unable to sign MacOS application from cronjob

Tags: macos, cron, code-signing

I have a [script](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/qgis-mac-packager) that builds and `codesign` an application bundle for MacOS. When I run it from my user's profile, the application is correctly signed, and I can install it on other machines.

The command used is `codesign -s <identity> -v <path>`, where identity is found by `security find-identity -v -p codesigning`

But when I run the same script from `cronjob`, I got an error

```
error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

How it is possible to sign the application from cronjob?

Answer (score 1):

Changed from `cronjob` to `launchd` and the `codesign -s < identity> --keychain < keychain path> -v < path>` is OK

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to create a separate keychain with the codesigning certificate and pass the keychain path as an argument to codesign as:

```
codesign -s < identity> --keychain < keychain path> -v < path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move signing certificates from the login keychain to the system keychain.